# @OneToMany with @JoinTable and @Embedded

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have 3 tables representing a container-containee relationship like this:

```
create table Containee(id int, name varchar(100), primary key(id));
create table Container(id int, name varchar(100), sourceId int, sourceType varchar(100), primary key(id));
create table JoinTable(containeeId int, resourceId int, resourceType varchar(100), primary key(containeeId, resourceId, resourceType));
```

The hibernate entities are mapped as follows

```
@Entity
public class Containee {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;

@Basic
private String name;
}

@Entity
public class Container implements Serializable {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;

@Basic
private String name;

@Embedded
@AttributeOverrides({
    @AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "sourceId")),
    @AttributeOverride(name = "type", column = @Column(name = "sourceType"))
})
private DomainObject domainObject;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "JoinTable", 
    joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name="resourceId", referencedColumnName = "sourceId"),
        @JoinColumn(name="resourceType", referencedColumnName = "sourceType")
    }, 
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "containeeId")
)
private Collection<Containee> containees;
}
```

The embedded class is declared as

```
@Embeddable
public class DomainObject {
private int id;
private String type;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getType() {
    return type;
}
```

}

The above code doesn't work and I get the following error:

> referencedColumnNames(sourceId, sourceType) of containees referencing
>   Container not mapped to a single property.

If I however remove @Embedded domainObject field and replace it with 2 @Basic sourceId and sourceType, the same code works like a charm. I have tried numerous things but nothing seems to work with the @Embedded field too. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Adding 2 more @Basic fields for sourceId and sourceType fixed this!